# Why does chess.com's tactics player avoid taking the queen in this problem?

Tags: tactics

Why can't the black pawn take the queen at h6? Instead the computer makes the king go to g8.

[image]

Comment: HINT: What happens after 1. ... gxh6 2. Nxf6+?

Answer (score 13):

1... gxh6 2. Nxf6+ Kh8 3. Rg8#

```
[FEN "4rb2/pbqr2pk/1p3p1p/4p3/2P3NP/1P4R1/P5P1/2Q2B1K w - - 0 1"]

1. Qxh6+ gxh6 2. Nxf6+ Kh8 3. Rg8#
```

Answer (score 7):

The pawn on g7 performs two vital functions:

1. It protects the pawn on f6 from capture by the White knight.
2. It indirectly bars the way to g8 to the White rook on g3.

If it captures the queen on h6 (thereby "moving"), it loses both these functions. Then:

1. Nxf6+  Kh8
2. Rg8 mate.

For White, the checkmate would be well worth a queen, for Black, not.